# Is there a solution to $\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{3}}\;$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I saw this question in a book.

> Got the result of this phrase?
> $$A=\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{3}}$$

My attempt

$$A^3=\left(\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{3}}\right)^3=4+3\left(\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{3}}\right)=4+3A$$
$$A^3-3A-4=0$$

Comment: What to find? Be more precise

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  It might help to give the book"s title and author, and cite the chapter or page where the problem was found.

Comment: If you are trying to simplify $A$ by solving that cubic equation, you'll end up getting the same value of $A$ from which you started.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha. If you solve the cubic (only one real root) using the hyperbolic method, you also have $A=2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}(2)\right)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yeah. That will also be equal to $\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{3}}$. Thanks for the information.

Comment: can this radical be denested?